# Get number of posts per day in wordpress

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I'm using Google analytics to monitor the visits to a wordpress blog. I cannot see the number of posts and map them to the number of visits...

Is there a plugin that can show me the number of posts and even better also the number of visits per day in wordpress? Or is there a way to get number of posts per day in wordpress?

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, my hunch is that using Google Analytics alone for that is probably taking the more difficult path (if it's even possible). GA is more for user interaction, where posts per day data is more server-side/internal tracking.

The post dates are all stored in MySQL though, so you can probably mash up the data one-off in Excel or use the GA API and write your own little script to merge both sources.

Comment: I think there should be a simpler way... even if I get only the posts per day alone on a graph will be enough I think, so maybe focusing more on wordpress... Do you think there is any plugin for that?

Comment: I'm not aware of a plugin but if you know a bit of SQL you can probably monkey through it. I can't imagine it being a plugin since the average user doesn't post more than once or so per day. Do you have PHPMyAdmin? That's probably the easiest way to get to it. Something like `select post_date, count(distinct post_title) from table where post_date between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'`. That'll give you a count of posts for each day there were posts.